# Preserve cursor position when using ==

Tags: vim, indentation, auto-indent

I am trying to make Vim indent lines like Emacs (that is, "make the current line the correct indent" instead of "insert tab character"). Vim can do this with <kbd>=</kbd> (or <kbd>==</kbd>) for one line). I have `imap <Tab> <Esc>==i` in my .vimrc but this makes the cursor move to the first non-space character on the line. I would like the cursor position to be preserved, so I can just hit tab and go back to typing without having to adjust the cursor again. Is this possible?

### Example

- What I have now (`|` represents the cursor):

  ```
  function f() {
  doso|mething();
  }
  ```

  <kbd>Tab</kbd>

  ```
  function f() {
      |dosomething();
  }
  ```
- What I would like:

  ```
  function f() {
  doso|mething();
  }
  ```

  <kbd>Tab</kbd>

  ```
  function f() {
      doso|mething();
  }
  ```

  Also

  ```
  function f() {
   |  dosomething();
  }
  ```

  <kbd>Tab</kbd>

  ```
  function f() {
     |dosomething();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's an "easy" way to do this (that is, with strictly built-in functionality) but a simple function does it just fine.  In your `.vimrc` file:

```
function! DoIndent()       
    " Check if we are at the *very* end of the line
    if col(".") == col("$") - 1
        let l:needsAppend = 1
    else
        let l:needsAppend = 0
    endif

    " Move to location where insert mode was last exited
    normal `^

    " Save the distance from the first nonblank column
    let l:colsFromBlank = col(".")
    normal ^
    let l:colsFromBlank = l:colsFromBlank - col(".")

    " If that distance is less than 0 (cursor is left of nonblank col) make it 0
    if l:colsFromBlank < 0                            
        let l:colsFromBlank = 0
    endif

    " Align line
    normal ==

    " Move proper number of times to the right if needed
    if l:colsFromBlank > 0
        execute "normal " . l:colsFromBlank . "l"
    endif

    " Start either insert or line append
    if l:needsAppend == 0
        startinsert
    else
        startinsert!
    endif
endfunction                                   

" Map <Tab> to call this function                                          
inoremap <Tab> <ESC>:call DoIndent()<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. It was almost working before, but your last edit made it a bit wonky. Before you edited it, it was working except for when the cursor was at the end of the line, or at the beginning.

Comment: Hrrm.  Let me test it a little more rigorously.  Give me a minute.

Comment: @Johnny I believe it has been fixed now.

Comment: And thanks for the comments too, I'm trying now to modify it so that it works in Normal mode too and the comments make it a lot easier.

Comment: For future visitors, adding the line `nnoremap <Tab> i<ESC>:call DoIndent()<CR><ESC>l` at the end seems to make it work just as well in Normal mode. Thanks again Riley, wish I could upvote multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

There's always `<C-T>` and `<C-D>` (that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) in insert mode to indent and outdent on the fly.

These don't change the cursor position – and they're built-in functionality.

Comment: This isn't quite what I need, I'm looking for the "magic indent" of Emacs, not "add/subtract indentation".

Answer (score 0):

Try using a mark of last insert mode, and use the append command to set the cursor back just where it was before, like:

```
:imap <Tab> <Esc>==`^a
```

Comment: Cursory testing shows this not to work, as the mark is based on the column in which it is set, not the actual text in the line.  As such, it doesn't move back to the right place.

Comment: @Riley: You are right. This answer is incorrect. **glts's** answer is the good one for me.